# Table is mutating, trigger cant read or modify it

Tags: sql, oracle

Table is mutating, trigger cant read or modify it, ORACLE SQL

I have table summons(Hour, DataJogo, EquipaID, NIF, MinutesPlayed)
Where Minutes played are normally 90.
However, I have a table(Hour, DataJogo, EquipaID, IF, Minute, TipoAcaoID)
And the problem is, if a player has a red card (ActionTypeID(TipoAcaoID) = 8), for example) on the minute 32, the summons table should change the MinutesPlayed to 32.

This is my trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_if_red_card_or_two_yellows_before_insert_new_summon
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON ACOES
FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
    ContagemAmarelos INT;
    ContagemVermelhos INT;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ContagemAmarelos
    FROM Acoes
    WHERE NIF = :NEW.NIF AND TipoAcaoID = 7 AND DataJogo = :NEW.DataJogo AND Hora = :NEW.Hora;
    
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ContagemVermelhos
    FROM Acoes
    WHERE NIF = :NEW.NIF AND TipoAcaoID = 8 AND DataJogo = :NEW.DataJogo AND Hora = :NEW.Hora;
    
    IF ContagemAmarelos = 2 THEN
        UPDATE CONVOCATORIA
        SET MinutosJogados = (
            SELECT Minuto
            FROM Acoes
            WHERE NIF = :NEW.NIF AND TipoAcaoID = 7 AND DataJogo = :NEW.DataJogo AND Hora = :NEW.Hora
        );
            
    ELSIF ContagemVermelhos = 1 THEN
        UPDATE CONVOCATORIA
        SET MinutosJogados = (
            SELECT Minuto
            FROM Acoes 
            WHERE NIF = :NEW.NIF AND TipoAcaoID = 8 AND DataJogo = :NEW.DataJogo AND Hora = :NEW.Hora
        );
    END IF;
END;
/
```

The trigger compiles, but when I try to insert values into actions I get the error in the title.

Comment: you can't do a select on the table that the trigger is for like that  read up on compound triggers.

Comment: what if I can't use compound triggers? Is there another way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: There's no way to access the table being modified in a row level trigger. Use compound trigger or materialized view that will automatically calculate values based on the table or control the calculation at the app code.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert multiple rows in single statement. You can also update multiple rows in single statement. MERGE statement can insert and update multiple rows at once.

And now imagine what happens when your trigger gets executed, the order of rows is random, so your trigger get executed on every row at random order.

This "Table is mutating" error can be read as Oracle is telling you: "I can not guarantee, that your code is deterministic". If you executed the same UPDATE/MERGE/INSERT in two databases having the same data, the result could be different.

Common ways how to overcome this situation:

- place business logic into a PROCEDURE having PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION annotation. Such a procedure would not be able to see any uncommitted data. So AFAIK in your case it would not help.
- Use compound trigger, collect necessary data in `BEFORE` part of the trigger, store them in local variables, and apply changes in `AFTER` part of the trigger.
- Use both `BEFORE` and `AFTER` trigger, store data in package variable, and apply changes in AFTER trigger.

NOTE: Data you need to collect have to be kind of hash map (`TABLE OF datatype [NOT NULL] INDEX BY ...;`. So you can capture changes for each row modified by your statement.